# Android SDK: Media Player - Load video stream from HTTP url

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player

I have a MediaPlayerActivity with the following code:
This code basically tries to get a video stream from a http url and load it but for some reason it keeps crashing.

```
public class MediaPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.video_player);
        SurfaceView v = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_video); 
        SurfaceHolder holder = v.getHolder(); 
        holder.setFixedSize(400,300); 

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("http://stream-url.com/playlist.m3u8")); 
        mp.setDisplay(holder);
        //mp.setAudioStreamType(2); 
        try {
            //mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

video_player.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
> 
<SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface_video" 
android:layout_width="250px" 
android:layout_height="250px"> 
</SurfaceView> 
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:padding="10dip" 
> 
</LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

When I go to this activity using the following code it crashes:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MediaPlayerActivity.class);
                    HomeActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without logs, two suggestions:

1. try implementing `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceCreated()`.
2. try using `MediaPlayer.create()` that accepts `SurfaceHolder`

### Details of (1)

Maybe your surface is not yet created when you call `start()`. You should use `MediaPlayer.setDisplay()` and `MediaPlayer.start() only after surface is created. To do this, you should add override`SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceCreated()`. For example, your code could look like this.

```
public class MediaPlayerActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    MediaPlayer mp; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.video_player);
        SurfaceView v = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_video); 
        SurfaceHolder holder = v.getHolder(); 
        holder.setFixedSize(400,300);
        holder.addCallback(this). 

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("http://stream-url.com/playlist.m3u8")); 

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        mp.setDisplay(holder); 
        try {
            mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### Details of (2)

There seems to be other `MediaPlayer.create()` that accepts `SurfaceHolder` as one of the arguments - you could try it: `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context, android.net.Uri, android.view.SurfaceHolder)`

Comment: @user1417302 I've changed my answer, because previous was totally wrong (as create() seems to put MediaPlayer in prepared state).

Comment: @user1417302 Did my answer help you with your problem? Also if not, some logs would help.