# I am not able to play video from https link

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm using Media Player in my Android application. The videos from http link is playing in all versions of android, but the https link is playing only in Android 4.1.2, but in lower versions it is not playing. Showing following error..

```
java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1 Error(1,-18).
```

I'm using the following code

```
   MediaPlayerplayer = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
player.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
player.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
player.setDisplay(holder);

    try {
String videoUrl = getIntent().getExtras().get("url").toString();
    File mediaFile = new File(fileName);
if (mediaFile.exists()) {
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(mediaFile);
    player.setDataSource(fi.getFD());                   
    }
else{
    player.setDataSource(videoUrl);
}
```

Comment: Call reset() before setDataSource.

Comment: please have a look of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411792/android-sdk-media-player-video-from-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android versions above 3.1 only supports HTTPS media files. See the [official link](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core).

Comment: Excuse me. Where does it state that HTTP is not supported above Android 3.1

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
  try {
        setContentView(R.layout.videodisplay);
        String link="Yourvideo link";
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse(link);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

and give internet permission in android manifest.xml and if you want to play using mediaplayer than click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410834/android-sdk-media-player-load-video-stream-from-http-url)

Answer (score 1):

**After long struggle i found solution,that's why i share with you because it take too much time to find out answer**

> Override your videoview class and below code.

```
 @Override
public void setVideoURI(Uri uri) {
    super.setVideoURI(uri);
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);
        MySSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(MySSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        sf.fixHttpsURLConnection();
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```